# C# find lowest price between 2 lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a MVC Web Application as part of a University project. I'm retrieving 2 sets of 'products' from 2 different Web API microservices, both have the exact same 'products' but have different prices, they both use the following data models:

```
public int BrandId { get; set; }
public string BrandName { get; set; }
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
public string CategoryName { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Ean { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }
public bool InStock { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public double Price { get; set; }
```

I am storing the results from both API's in 2 Lists, but need a way of comparing and extracting the product from the one with the cheapest price, and then store it in a seperate list.

It's also worth noting that the 'EAN' string is the same across both API's also.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you go by comparing each entity from both lists and finding out the one you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Id` is a unique identifier that is common to both APIs, you can `Concatenate` the two lists, group them by `Id`, order each group by `Price`, and pick the one with the lower price:

```
var lowerPriced = allProductsOne.Concat(allProductsTwo)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Id)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(p => p.Price).First())
    .ToList();
```